# Using call-preserved registers vs just the stack for saving values around a function call

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Take:

```
void callee(void);
long call_and_ret_saved(long ToSave){
    callee();
    return ToSave;
}
```

where the generated assembly will need to save the value of the ToSave argument in order to be able to return it after the call to `callee`.

Both gcc and clang generate:

```
call_and_ret_saved:
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    call    callee
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

for it. Why not simply `push %rdi; call callee; pop %rax; ret;` ? Does using the call-preserved register make the return value available sooner or something?

Comment: What optimization level are you using? Try with -O3

Comment: @DarioPetrillo Their codegen for this is the same at all optimizing (!=-O0) levels https://godbolt.org/z/TWfP8ecbo.

Comment: Looks like a missed optimization to me -- or an unwarranted optimization choice to use a call-preserved register for that.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yup. That's an quintessential duplicate. Thanks.